# iPhone App size increased after uploading

Tags: iphone, app-store

A week before I have uploaded my iPhone app the zipped version size is 17.2MB, My app released today and it size turns out to be 20.2MB. Now its not possible to download that app through carrier network(since it crossed 20MB limit it needs WiFi). Why the size increased from 17.2 to 20.2MB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The executable (ARM code) inside the app bundle is encrypted by Apple, which means that it no longer gets compressed in size when zipped up into an ipa file.

To estimate the actual ipa size, replace the executable with some /dev/rand of the same size before a test zip of the app bundle.

Comment: Ya... The problem was the executable will not be compressed by apple.(They just do some encryption)

Answer (score 1):

Pay attention to how large the app is before it is zipped. The zip file is not what goes to the app store, you need to look at your actual app file.

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote a blog post on how exactly to check the [maximum size of a binary here](http://longweekendmobile.com/2011/12/21/20mb-limit-finding-the-real-size-of-an-app-binary/).

Short version:
Open the archive, find the executable, remove it, and add it's uncompressed size to the size of all the other files compressed to get the max size of the bundle after encryption and compression. Final size will be slightly smaller but no larger.